# Simple select word using a hotkey in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

#### Purpose

In Firefox, I want to select a word, no matter if the caret is situated at the beginning, middle, or end of the word, using a hotkey and not the mouse.

For example, it is done in Sublime Text by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> .

[image: Select word in Sublime Text]

#### My actions

- I did not find the shortcut at the [official Mozilla site](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_editing) .
- I did not find the answer searching `select word firefox` on Google either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

More or less a workaround, but you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> to move the cursor to the beginning of a word, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to select the following word.
Or the other way round, i.e. move the cursor to the end of the word by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>, then select the previous word by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>.

Comment: In this context, you also might want to check out the `layout.word_select.eat_space_to_next_word` in `about:config`. If set to `true`, Firefox will also select a space character - if any - following the word you selected. Set to `false` to not select the space character.